# Extremly slow SQL query with a lot of joins

Tags: mariadb, entity-attribute-value

I have a MariaDB database, that has 1 main table where customer info is put into. I then have 28 other tables that have menu options for the main table for the web form side. Each of the menu tables, has maybe 2-4 items in them. Each has 2 columns, id and value. id is indexed in each table.

I am doing a `SELECT customers.customer_name, menu_1.value AS customer_status,....` with a bunch of items like that. Then I have 28 or so JOINs. I know this is not optimized at all.

```
INNER JOIN menu_table_1 ON customers.status = menu_table_1.id
```

In this example menu_table_1.id is an int and so is customers.status.
This is taking forever to run. I only have 4 items in the customers table currently.

I also noticed while the query is running, the CPU maxes out. I haven't had the query finish yet.... But if I chop it down, it runs fine.

Comment: Sounds like "over-normalization".  Let's see a sample query.  Read about the problems with EAV.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query adding 1 join at a time to find what joins are bottle necks, then create an index on those fields which you are joining on, rerun query to see if it resolved the issue. Continue on and join the next table etc...

Comment: I am joining on the id column, which is indexed in each table.

Comment: When running individual queries on the customers and menu table does it result in any issues? Or do you get returns and no performance issues?   Do you have a where clause?   Can you post your sql in more detail?

Comment: Your alias is customers_status (underscore) but your join is on customers.status